# GUI missing since switching to ubuntu 23.04

Tags: graphics, intel-graphics, intel, msi, 23.04

Since I updated from Ubuntu 22.04 to Ubuntu 23.04, I no longer have a GUI, moreover after installing the update, several system applications were missing, such as the application settings or updates app, after manually reinstalling those apps and restarting the GUI no longer works and I don't know what to do, I looked everywhere and the idea of reinstalling ubuntu 23.04 becomes the best way to solve problems.
If you have better solutions to offer, I'm interested because I don't have many connections to reinstall apps.

[image: Here are error codes on startup]

Comment: Can you access a virtual terminal with `ctrl + alt + f3`? Also, did you upgrade via 22.10? Please edit the question to add more information.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution after having made the same error on another pc (I reproduced what I had done) and I noticed that I had deleted these packages:

```
2to3 apport apport-gtk aptdaemon cloud-init command-not-found deja-dup
  duplicity gdm3 gnome-control-center gnome-shell
  gnome-shell-extension-appindicator gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng
  gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock gnome-terminal hplip ibus ibus-table
  ibus-table-cangjie-big ibus-table-cangjie3 ibus-table-cangjie5 idle
  idle-python3.11 language-selector-common language-selector-gnome
  libpython3.11-testsuite mkdocs nautilus-extension-gnome-terminal netplan.io
  networkd-dispatcher orca
```

you have to reinstall them manually
with your kernel with `sudo apt install` and the package.

here is the list of all my packages:

```
2to3 apport apport-gtk aptdaemon cloud-init command-not-found deja-dup
  duplicity gdm3 gnome-control-center gnome-shell
  gnome-shell-extension-appindicator gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng
  gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock gnome-terminal hplip ibus ibus-table
  ibus-table-cangjie-big ibus-table-cangjie3 ibus-table-cangjie5 idle
  idle-python3.11 language-selector-common language-selector-gnome
  libpython3.11-testsuite mkdocs nautilus-extension-gnome-terminal netplan.io
  networkd-dispatcher orca pipx python3 python3-all python3-all-dev
  python3-apport python3-apt python3-aptdaemon python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets
  python3-bcrypt python3-brlapi python3-brotli python3-cairo
  python3-cffi-backend python3-commandnotfound python3-cryptography
  python3-cups python3-cupshelpers python3-dbus python3-dev
  python3-distupgrade python3-examples python3-fonttools python3-full
  python3-gdbm python3-gi python3-ibus-1.0 python3-jinja2 python3-jsonschema
  python3-keyring python3-kiwisolver python3-launchpadlib
  python3-lazr.restfulclient python3-livereload python3-lunr python3-lxml
  python3-lz4 python3-mako python3-markupsafe python3-matplotlib
  python3-minimal python3-nacl python3-netifaces python3-nltk python3-numpy
  python3-oauthlib python3-paramiko python3-pil python3-pil.imagetk
  python3-psutil python3-pyatspi python3-pyrsistent python3-pythran
  python3-pyyaml-env-tag python3-regex python3-renderpm python3-reportlab
  python3-reportlab-accel python3-scipy python3-secretstorage
  python3-simplejson python3-software-properties python3-sss python3-systemd
  python3-tk python3-tornado python3-ufolib2 python3-update-manager
  python3-venv python3-watchdog python3-yaml python3.11 python3.11-dev
  python3.11-full python3.11-minimal python3.11-venv
  rhythmbox-plugin-alternative-toolbar rhythmbox-plugins
  screen-resolution-extra software-properties-common software-properties-gtk
  sssd sssd-ad sssd-ad-common sssd-common sssd-ipa sssd-krb5 sssd-krb5-common
  sssd-ldap sssd-proxy system-config-printer system-config-printer-common
  system-config-printer-udev totem-plugins ubuntu-advantage-desktop-daemon
  ubuntu-advantage-tools ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-desktop-minimal
  ubuntu-drivers-common ubuntu-minimal ubuntu-release-upgrader-core
  ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk ubuntu-session unattended-upgrades
  update-manager update-manager-core update-notifier update-notifier-common
  usb-creator-common usb-creator-gtk virtualbox virtualbox-qt xorg
  xserver-xorg
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. It worked for a couple of months, though. Now when I turn on the machine I can only get the terminal, not the gui. I noticed a lot of talk about this from years past, but everything they suggested did not work for me.
How is it that there is no support evident in the linux community? Lots of questions are answered (not) with questions! I am going to try reinstalling 23.04 (Yes, I did go from 22.04 to 22.10 to 23.04).